# bootstrap printing width

Tags: printing, twitter-bootstrap, width

I'm using bootstrap in an app and as you can see (below) when printing the browser (left side)
is using a really small width when printing (right) so the responsive layout is moving all the right site elements below the left side ones and the printing version won't fit in one single page.

Do you know how can I force the browser to keep the right width?

Thanks,

Remo

[image: Valid XHTML].

Comment: Did my answer help? Your problem really seems to match mine. If it solves your problem I'll ask the bootstrap developers to mention the `media="screen"` attribute in their docs: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/scaffolding.html#L389

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had a very similar problem.
Ensuring the [responsive css](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) is enabled only for `media="screen"` solved it.

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Comment: If you're loading from bootstrapcdn.com, the later version do not have a separate `bootstrap-responsive.css`, only `bootstrap-combined.min.css` which is everything including the responsive styles, and `bootstrap.min.css` which is everything except the responsive styles. As a work-around, you can load both files with separate `media` settings: `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">` & `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">`

Comment: If you notice the two different version numbers, that's because of this bug https://github.com/netdna/bootstrap-cdn/pull/106 . In v2.3.2 `bootstrap.min.css` includes the responsive styles, when it should not.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with bootstrap 3?

Comment: @fande455 [bootstrap 3 has native css classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-print) you can apply to toggle items that should display when printing.

Comment: @ScottWoodall, is there anything more than hidden + visible classes for bootstrap 3 to fix this?  It would mean a ton of duplicate html if I have to create separate states for print/screen.

Comment: @BrianABird These classes are what is available: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-print

Answer (score 8):

For Bootstrap 3, this solved my problem:

```
@media print {
  .container {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not for me. It gets out of the page.

Comment: But a fixed width did the trick `@media print { body { width:992px; } }` thanks for the idea.

Comment: This fixed the full width problem for me perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Getting rid of the responsive style is the answer! thanks a lot !

I'm using rails twitter bootstrap, that recompiles the less sources, so just a little note to say that it works like this too (first line of bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less):

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
@media screen {
    @import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive.less";
}
```

oops: edit, it works fine in development, but brings error when compiling for production... had to build 2 distinct bootstrap_and_overrides for screen and print version (looking for a cleaner solution)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has something like this:

```css
@media print
body {
  min-width: 992px !important;
}
```

So you can use an inline `css` like this to override above rule and make printed media fit page's width:

```html
<body style="min-width:100%!important">
```

(A new `!important` css rule has problem overriding a similar one and I think the only (simple) way to override above rule is to use an inline `css`)