# Issue with Print function for RWD

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, printing

I have developed Page using RWD help of bootstrap.while printing the page its taking mobile view.my Requirement is have to print as desktop.How to achieve this issue please help.

Comment: check answers on this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246096/bootstrap-printing-width

Comment: Thank you @Helga.I have fixed because of shared link.